# How to Install PHPSpreadsheet in Joomla

Tags: joomla, composer-php, phpspreadsheet

I'm wondering how to best incorporate PHPSpreadsheet into Joomla! applications, on shared hosting.

With PHPExcel, you just uploaded the library.

PHPSpreadsheet is using Composer, which is new to me, but looks straightforward enough.  However, I see Joomla! includes it to manage dependencies in the core, but does not publish the `composer.json` file, and commits the `/vendor` subfolder.

Any advice on the best way to safely add PHPSpreadsheet so its available to Joomla! extensions, without messing up Joomla! core?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a normal `composer.json` file in Joomla's root folder. Composer will then create a `vendor` folder on the main level, and leave the `libraries/vendor` folder unchanged for the Joomla core.

Any extension that wants to use libraries from the root `vendor` folder must take care of loading the corresponding `vendor/autoload.php` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
JLoader::registerNamespace('PhpOffice', $pathToPhpOffice);
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar lines to the above....  But how do you get PHPSpreadsheet installed on my hosted website, where I have limited access to the back end.

I can FTP to the root of the site.