# Is possible use PhpSpreadsheet inside of Joomla CMS?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, phpspreadsheet

Im creating some new joomla components, all of them need to work exporting data into Excel, so I think PhpSpreadsheet is a good library for that requirement, but how can I install it inside of joomla? in that way all my components can use that library. Like its using Composer for installation I dont know how to manage it inside Joomla or my compoments.

Comment: I check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267571/how-to-install-phpspreadsheet-in-joomla but looks like its not the correct way to do it, right?

Comment: Please include you best (but not working) attempt in your question so that it doesn't look like you are seeking a complete tutorial.  When you have Joomla-specific issues/questions, please post at Joomla Stack Exchange.

Comment: I was asking for ideas not for a complete solution.

Comment: Future researchers that find your question via Google search will not value an idea as much as a complete solution.  Remember, volunteers are not _only_ trying to help you, they are trying to help thousands of researchers in the future as well.

Comment: So? Is this the place for find a complete solution or not? Anyways looks like nobody have a clue about my question...

Comment: I know I don't have an answer, because I only started to use Joomla in March of this year.  My point is, you should post your question on Joomla Stack Exchange to see if anyone over there knows a solution.

Comment: Take a look at this tread. May be something for you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767355/how-to-use-phpspreadsheet-without-installation-like-phpexcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767355/how-to-use-phpspreadsheet-without-installation-like-phpexcel)